# Indesign Text in two columns and several textframes

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am importing records from a database with a plugin into one big textframe in InDesing CS6. The layout defines a textframe with 2 columns per page. The datas are addresses, sorted by country. Each country is shown as a running header in a header section.

The layout should be changed now: Per country all adresses will be in a separate textframe. Each textframe has a title, the tile of the country, spanned over the two columns. Imagine, that one page we have three countries. So the first will start with a spanned paragraph for its title. Then there are mayby four adresses in the first column and 3 in the second one. 
Then we go over to the next country in the next textframe (still threaded).

My problem: How can I split one textframe in a way, that I get the layout above? We are talking about a index of 200 pages and more than 4000 addresses. Can this probabely be done by a paragraph break rule? Scripting?

Example:

[image: columnar text, before and after]

Comment: Can you give a visual example please?

Comment: Image is added externaly. See original post Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since CS5 the paragraph styles editor has a sub-panel "Span Columns". Set your country headline paragraph style to Paragraph Layout:  "Span Columns", Span: "All" and you're done.

Please explain if you still need separate text frames.

Comment: Thanks. I know this function but I didn't expect that it will arrange the text between two spanned paragraphs correctly. But it does. Great! Thanks again!